# JSONP invalid content-type response header breaking execution on Firefox

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp, content-type

I have a JSONP call that returns the following response payload:

```
Object.callback({
    "status":201,
    "results":{"status":"success","type":"token"}
})
```

with the content-type response header **application/json**. It is pretty clear that the above response is not a valid JSON and that the content type should be **application/javascript**.

> RFC recommandations:
>
> - use application/json if the response is plain json [rfc4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)
> - use application/javascript if the response is JavaScript (which is really what JSONP is) - [rfc4329](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt)

While Chrome is tolerant in this case, Firefox is not. It is issuing the following error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 8 of the JSON data
```

breaking the rest of the script execution. I'm using the latest FF version.

[image]
The problem is that I can't manipulate the content-type response header. There are small chances that the endpoint owner will fix it anytime soon so I need a workaround.

The request is issued by this js lib (see line 76) https://github.com/payeezy/payeezy_js/blob/master/example/payeezy_intl_v5.2.js

and a sample request URL:

```
https://api-cert.payeezy.com/v1/securitytokens?apikey=JBGWWqLqvUZKHNidRYZnds4uAJ2Sqlz8&js_security_key=js-70e964a7abbc105e02e57fcec1c2207070e964a7abbc105e&callback=Payeezy.callback&auth=true&ta_token=NOIW&type=FDToken&credit_card.type=Visa&credit_card.cardholder_name=John%20Doe&credit_card.card_number=4111111111111111&credit_card.exp_date=0424&credit_card.cvv=123
```

Is there a way?

Comment: how are you *loading* this JSONP - i.e. the javascript code

Comment: like this - https://api-cert.payeezy.com/v1/securitytokens?apikey=JBGWWqLqvUZKHNidRYZnds4uAJ2Sqlz8&js_security_key=js-70e964a7abbc105e02e57fcec1c2207070e964a7abbc105e&callback=Payeezy.callback&auth=true&ta_token=NOIW&type=FDToken&credit_card.type=Visa&credit_card.cardholder_name=John%20Doe&credit_card.card_number=4111111111111111&credit_card.exp_date=0424&credit_card.cvv=123

Comment: no, that's just a link - how is your code generating that link and then trying to load the JSONP

Comment: see line 76 in https://github.com/payeezy/payeezy_js/blob/master/example/payeezy_intl_v5.2.js - I will add this two links in the question body as well

Comment: I wonder if adding `f.type="application/javascript"` would help?

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't have any effect, although it would have been a nice feature.

Comment: the only workaround I can think of would be to possibly proxy the request  using your server, and fix the content-type in your proxy response